# Where does logrotate save its own log?

Tags: logrotate

I have `logrotate` running in an EC2 AWS machine rotating Apache logs. Once packed, Apache logs are saved into AWS S3 via s3fs. The problem is that I recently noticed that I didn't have logs rotated. In S3 I have old logs from day 48->60 but the 1->47 doesn't appear.

My question is: Where does logrotate save its own log? It's possible that I have some kind of problem with s3fs, but I need to know before I do anything. I tried to find somewhere the logs but I couldn't find it out.

Any idea?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`logrotate` does not log anything by default. normally it should be in your cron somewhere, for instance:

```
$ grep -r -- 'logrotate.conf' /etc/cron*
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

You can either run that manually to see what is wrong, or redirect the logrotate output to a file in the above cron to see what happened next day.

Likely somewhere the config is incorrect and caused the logrotate run to break.

Comment: +1 on running logrotate manually to see what's wrong

Comment: thanks for the answer, but what I really want to know what has happened in my system to get this kind result. Thank's!

Comment: does manually run logrotate give any errors? if there are errors, you need to fix them in the conf file or /etc/logrotate.d/apache (or apache2).

Comment: You can use the `-d` debug flag and the `-f` force flag to see exactly what logrotate is attempting to do. `-d` disables action but the printed messages will still claim they're changing things.

Comment: When running `/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf`, I'd add `-v` to see the detailed log.

Comment: Combining everyone's suggestions, it sounds like manually running `logrotate -dfv` is most helpful. My command already had `-s <statefile>` on it, so I ended up using `logrotate -dsfv <statefile>` for debugging.

Answer (score 23):

The only thing that logrotate records normally is in `cat /var/lib/logrotate/status`.

This is taken from https://serverfault.com/a/518134/266525

Comment: It turns out there are differences in the actual path depending on the distribution and version used. Check the linked serverfault answer and it's comments for details.

Comment: `/var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status` on my CentOS 7 system.

Answer (score 9):

Another good place to look is `/var/log/messages` on CentOS for errors such as this from the cron.daily `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`

```
logrotate: ALERT exited abnormally with [1]
```

You can also run in debug mode manually and check for errors:

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Source: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/32831

Answer (score 4):

If you're running `logrotate` from cron and not redirecting the output, the output, if there is any, will go to email for whichever ID is running the cron job.  I redirect my output to a log file.

For example:

```
25 3 * * 7 /usr/sbin/logrotate -s /home/user/conf/mwarelogrotate.state 
/home/user/conf/mwarelogrotate.conf >> /home/user/logs/logrotate.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2):

When logrotate doesn't rotate logs or enters failed state, it's a good idea to run logorate manually in debug mode to see what errors it lists, like this:

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.d/*
```

This command tests rotating the logs for all the services that have files located in `/etc/logrotate.d`. If it lists errors (such as errors caused by duplicate log entries), you'll know why logrotate has problems.

Answer (score 1):

Check `/etc/logrotate.conf` for global config settings that may be affecting tasks configured through `/etc/logrotate.d/`